# 実行時にエラーが出る次のプログラムのコンパイルが通ってしまうのはどうしてでしょうか

Tags: macos, haskell

以下のHaskellコードはGHCで問題なくコンパイルされます。

```
f :: String -> MaybeT IO String
f x =
    MaybeT $ do
        s <- getLine
        case s of
         "y" ->
             pure . pure =<< getLine
         _ ->
             empty
```

実行すると`empty`のケースのときエラーになってしまいます。

```
> runMaybeT $ f "a"
b
*** Exception: user error (mzero)
```

`empty`のケースの型が間違っているので、そこを修正すれば動作します。

```
f :: String -> MaybeT IO String
f x =
    MaybeT $ do
        s <- getLine
        case s of
         "y" ->
             pure . pure =<< getLine
         _ ->
             pure empty
```

期待どおりになります。

```
> runMaybeT $ f "a"
b
Nothing
```

最初のコードを型エラーとしてコンパイル時にはじいてほしいのですが、どうして型チェックをすりぬけてしまうのでしょうか。
GHCに与えるオプションの調整が必要でしょうか。`-Wall`は付けています。

環境は以下です。

> uname -v
>   Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
>   ghc -V
>   The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.1

---

追記： `import`しているモジュールの定義による影響であるという指摘がありましたので、どれが該当するのか調べました

LibZip-0.11.1パッケージの

```
import Codec.Archive.LibZip
```

または ListLike-4.2.0パッケージの

```
import System.Process.ListLike
```

のいづれかの行を追加したときにコンパイルエラーにならず、実行時エラーになりました。
どちらもimportしなければ、期待どおりコンパイルエラーになります。

どちらでも発生するので、このモジュールそのものではなく、内部でimportしている別のモジュールが影響しているのだろうと思いましたが、それがどれなのかまでは僕のスキルでは特定できませんでした。

Comment: ghc 7.8.3 などでは[エラーが出るようです](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/y3npW6BVr2ABBwkF)（7.10 は試せていません）．

Comment: インスタンスがどのモジュールで定義されているのかを調べる方法を追記しておきました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

提示されたコードに必要な`import`を追加しただけで試すと、GHC-7.10.1ではコンパイルエラーになります。

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

f :: String -> MaybeT IO String
f x =
    MaybeT $ do
        s <- getLine
        case s of
         "y" ->
             pure . pure =<< getLine
         _ ->
             empty
```

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

```
a.hs:21:14:
    No instance for (Alternative IO) arising from a use of ‘empty’
    In the expression: empty
    In a case alternative: _ -> empty
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      case s of {
        "y" -> pure . pure =<< getLine
        _ -> empty }
```

提示された実行時のエラーメッセージ（`*** Exception: user error (mzero)`）から想像すると、他にインポートしているモジュールの中で、以下の様な形のIOに対するAlternativeのインスタンスが宣言されているのではないかと思います。

```
instance MonadPlus IO where
    mzero = fail "mzero"
    mplus = undefined -- 実行時例外をキャッチするような実装（省略）

instance Alternative IO where
    empty = mzero
    (<|>) = mplus
```

このようなインスタンス宣言を追加した上で試すと、コンパイルエラーにはなりませんし、実行時には提示されたエラーが発生します。

---

追記

インスタンスがどのモジュールで定義されているかは、ghciの`:info`コマンドを使うと確認できます。例えば、`System.Process.ListLike`をインポートした状態で試すと以下の様な出力が得られ、該当のインスタンスは、`Control.Monad.Trans.Error`で定義されていることがわかります。

```
Prelude> :m Control.Applicative Control.Monad System.Process.ListLike
Prelude Control.Applicative Control.Monad System.Process.ListLike> :info IO
newtype IO a
  = GHC.Types.IO (GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld
                  -> (# GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld, a #))
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Monad IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Applicative IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance MonadPlus IO -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Error’
instance Alternative IO -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Error’
```

Comment: なるほど! 試行錯誤でたくさんのimportがある状態なのでそのなかのどれかに問題がありそうです。調べてみます